# App crashes when I create a new bullet [Andoid Studio]

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm trying to get my player to spawn a bullet every time I tap on the screen. However, every time I do so it crashes and gives me this error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-3
    Process: com.example.mgp2021, PID: 20750
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.graphics.Bitmap.getWidth()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.mgp2021.Bullet.Render(Bullet.java:57)
```

Here is the bullet's script:

```
package com.example.spaceshooter;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceView;


public class Bullet implements EntityBase{
    private boolean isDone = false;
    private Bitmap bullet = null, scaledbmp = null;

    public float xPos = 0;
    public float yPos = 0;

    private float yLimit = 0;
    //float imgRadius = bullet.getHeight() * 0.5f;

    @Override
    public boolean IsDone() {
        return isDone;
    }

    @Override
    public void SetIsDone(boolean _isDone) {
        isDone = _isDone;
    }

    @Override
    public void Init(SurfaceView _view) {
        bullet = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(_view.getResources(), R.drawable.bullet);
        //setting up values
        xPos = DraggablePlayer.Instance.xPos;
        yPos = DraggablePlayer.Instance.yPos;
        //yLimit = _view.getHeight() * 0.5f;
    }


    @Override
    public void Update(float _dt) {
        yPos -= _dt * 300.f;

        if(bullet == null)
        {
            Log.e("ERR","Failed to decode resource bullet");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void Render(Canvas _canvas) {
        Matrix transform = new Matrix();
        transform.postTranslate(-bullet.getWidth()*0.5f, -bullet.getHeight()*0.5f);
        transform.postTranslate(xPos, yPos);
        _canvas.drawBitmap(bullet, transform, null);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean IsInit() {
        return bullet != null;
    }

    @Override
    public int GetRenderLayer() {
        return LayerConstants.BULLET_LAYER;
    }

    @Override
    public void SetRenderLayer(int _newLayer) {
    }

    @Override
    public ENTITY_TYPE GetEntityType() {
        return ENTITY_TYPE.ENT_BULLET;
    }

    public static Bullet Create() {
        Bullet result = new Bullet();
        EntityManager.Instance.AddEntity(result, ENTITY_TYPE.ENT_BULLET);
        return result;
    }
}
```

and here is the script for when I spawn the bullets:

```
public void Update(float _dt) {

        EntityManager.Instance.Update(_dt);

       if (TouchManager.Instance.IsDown())
       {
            Bullet.Create();
       }
    }
```

I'm really unsure of what's causing this error, any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Where does your variable `bullet` comes from?

Comment: The bitmap instance on line 57 is null, so you can't call getWidth() on a null object reference.

Comment: You should check initializing new a value to bullet variable in method "Init", default value is NULL given by you when declare it, crash appears because that variable value is null, maybe reading drawable "R.drawable.bullet" return null value check it

Comment: @VojinPurić   `private Bitmap bullet = null, scaledbmp = null;`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you call static `Create` method of your bullet class that return you an instance of `Bullet` but you **never call** (judging from code you posted) `Init` method that will actually read the contents of your `R.drawable.bullet` into a bitmap object.

**Answer:**
Make sure you call `Init` before `Render`.

---

Compare creation of `Bullet` object to creation of other objects that work in your app (I'm talking about objects implementing `EntityBase`).